# MySQLdb and regular expression in python

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
import MySQLdb
x=raw_input('user> ')
y=raw_input('passwd> ')
db=MySQLdb.Connect(host="localhost", user="%s", passwd="%s" % x,y)
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute('GRANT ALL ON squidctrl.* TO sams@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "connect";')
cursor.execute('GRANT ALL ON squidlog.* TO sams@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "connect";')
cursor.close()
```

question how can i use it right, i don't want to enter username and password in script in beginning, i want to it by myself as i wish. when i try it run i put username and pass, after that mistake

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    db=MySQLdb.Connect('host="localhost", user="%s", passwd="%s"' % x,y)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use string interpolation (`"%s" % ...`) here.

```
import MySQLdb
user = raw_input('user> ')
password = raw_input('passwd> ')
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user=user, passwd=password)
cursor=db.cursor()
cursor.execute('GRANT ALL ON squidctrl.* TO sams@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "connect";')
cursor.execute('GRANT ALL ON squidlog.* TO sams@localhost IDENTIFIED BY "connect";')
cursor.close()
```

Comment: I changed the variable names for the `raw_input` prompts too - if you just changed the `MySQLdb.connect` line in your code, adjust the variable names too.

Comment: @user1259251: please accept this answer as correct (if you can) via the checkmark icon on the left, underneath the up/downvote buttons then. :)

Comment: This is bad answer, cause problem not in using inerpolation, but this is syntax error, db=MySQLdb.Connect('host="localhost", user="%s", passwd="%s"' % (x,y)) thats will work fine. If you have more then one variable for interpolation you must pass tuple of vars to %.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    db=MySQLdb.Connect('host="localhost", user= "%s", passwd = "%s"' % (x,y))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 170, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, 'Unknown MySQL server host \'host="localhost", user= "root", passwd = "connect"\' (1)')                             ........................mistake

Comment: And so, dont you see what it's a another exception? Did you setup your  password as "connect"\' (1)' for root access? Be patience.